# Access private field in tested class in JUnit with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I the class I am testing I have a field, let's call it `private List<Person> people`. In the test I want to verify that a certain object with certain states is created. So I need to access that list and the created object in it after I have run the method.

I am using JUnit and Mockito.

Example Test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Testclass {

    @InjectMock 
    private TestedClass tested;

    @Mock(name = "personer")
    private List<Person> personerMock;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws BaseException {
        PersonA personA = kalle_KMD();
        when(personService.getPerson(any(), any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(personA));
        Properties p = new Properties();
        JobbParametrar params = JobbParametrar.skapa(p);
        batch.uppgift(new PersonIdÄrFöretag(1L, false), params, new KörningsId(1L), user);
        assertEquals(1, personerMock.size());
    }
}
```

And class to test:

```
public TestedClass {
    private List<Person> persons = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Person>());

    public void testedMethod() {
        ...
        PersonA personA = personService.getPerson(identitet, användare);
        Person p = createPerson(personA);
        persons.add(p);
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, how can I test an object (`Person p`) is created an added to the list, and access that object to see its values? Or should I have a totally different approach and not use Mockito in this case?
Mocking the instance field `personerMock`, like I did in this example, in the test class doesn't work.

Comment: you can test that `persons` has one more entry and `the person p is part of persons and the data from personA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it should work, but you need to capture the argument to the add.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Person> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
verify(personerMock).add(captor.capture());
Person createdPerson = captor.getValue();
// verify the values you're expecting in the person
```